# image resize in my wordpress plugin using php

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to resize an image in my wordpress plugin using php, But they don't work. How can I resize image as propotion wise using php?

anyone know if that's possible?

Thanks

Comment: There is a tool called TimThumb :http://www.binarymoon.co.uk/projects/timthumb/

Answer (score 1):

You can use wordpress built-in resize function:

```
<?php image_resize( $file, $max_w, $max_h, $crop, $suffix, $dest_path, $jpeg_quality ); ?>
```

You can find more details in here: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/image_resize

Answer (score 0):

This function takes the imagePath as parameter and the size to which you want it to resize the image.This will resize image with proportion constraints

suppose size = 300
then there will be three scenarios

1) if image's height is greater than width then its height will be 300

2) if width is greater then its width will be 300

3) if image is of ratio 1:1 then both its height and width will be of size 300

```
function resizeImage($imagePath,$size)
{
    $sizeData = getimagesize($imagePath);
    $width = $sizeData[0];
    $height = $sizeData[1];     

    # Loading image to memory according to type
    switch ( $sizeData[2] ) {
      case IMAGETYPE_GIF: $src = imagecreatefromgif($imagePath); break;
      case IMAGETYPE_JPEG: $src = imagecreatefromjpeg($imagePath); break;
      case IMAGETYPE_PNG: $src = imagecreatefrompng($imagePath); break;
      default: return false;
    }
    if(!$src)
    {
        return false;
    }
    if($height >= $width)
    {
        $newheight = $size;
        $newwidth = ($newheight*$width)/$height;            
    }
    else
    {
        $newwidth = $size;
        $newheight = ($height/$width)*$newwidth;            
    }       
    $tmp = imagecreatetruecolor($newwidth,$newheight);

    imagecopyresampled($tmp,$src,0,0,0,0,$newwidth,$newheight,$width,$height);

    # Writing image according to type to the output destination
    switch ( $sizeData[2] ) {
      case IMAGETYPE_GIF: imagegif($tmp, $imagePath); break;
      case IMAGETYPE_JPEG: imagejpeg($tmp, $imagePath, 100); break;
      case IMAGETYPE_PNG: imagepng($tmp, $imagePath, 9); break;
      default: return false;
    }
    imagedestroy($src);
    imagedestroy($tmp);
    return true;
}
```